# HPGL File Viewer in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hello Respected Everyone,

I'm a Beginner level programmer having working knowledge of vb.net. Currently I'm working on a program in VB.NET, which will extract labels from an HPGL file and print them on Thermal Printer. I've successfully read and extracted the Label Values from Label  Command. Now I'm trying to create an HPGL viewer in my Program. I've searched the internet for any Library or sample program which can guide me through but haven't found any reasonable answer. Please Guide me how can I view an HPGL File in a vb.net program.

I'll provide more information if needed.
Thank You in advance...

Comment: What did you mean you have extracted the labels from command? Does that mean using a command in command prompt?

Comment: @preciousbetine, I meant that I've extracted the label Values from Label Command (<LB>).

Comment: <LB> is an HPGL Command. It stores the String Values of Labels.